# send_file with authentication in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I use ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.0.4, and Redmine 1.4.4

I want to access to downloading a PDF only if I have the right.

My controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  unloadable

  def myFunction
    # code that create a pdf

    File.open(myPdf, 'r') do |file|
      send_file file, :filename => myPdf, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

If I try to access to my PDF without being logged, I can download it, so I need to check the authentication.

I tried `http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "name", :password => "psw"` and it give me `(undefined method 'http_basic_authenticate_with' for myController:Class`.

I tried `before_action :authenticate`, it give me `undefined method 'before_action' for myController:Class`.

I tried `before_filter :authenticate_user` ... and it give me `undefined method 'authenticate_user' for #<myController:0x000000064f20d0>`

I should use `before_action` because it's Rails 4, why it dosen't work ?

How can I do ?

EDIT: I don't want that all users could access to the pdf, just the ones I give right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this feature in my project:

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate, only: :billing_pdf

  def billing_pdf
    # i save my pdf file in private folder
    send_file Rails.root.join('private', "billing_pdf"), type: "application/pdf", x_sendfile: true
  end

   def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic('Administration') do |username, password|
      username == 'admin' && password == 'password'
    end
  end
end
```

in views:

```
<%= link_to 'Download Billing', download_billing_pdf_path %>
```

in routes:

```
namespace :download do
  get 'billing_pdf'
end
```

Comment: Yes, my mistake for my class name, I edit my post. Your solution loop on the authenticate (I copy/past it!), what I am doing wrong? But it's not exacly what I want (sorry, I say it badly): my controller is called with a link_to. I want users can download the pdf only if they click on the link and no other ways. Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: In a simple way: I want to do exactly like the pdf export in Redmine

Comment: i use this feature in my project, look code what i use in update answer.